# fscanf fails reading tab values

Tags: c, file, io, scanf

I am writing a simple C program to read float values from a tab file using `fscanf`.

Here is the tab file:

```
>     7             <--------------this declares the number of pairs of values
>     4.0     5.0
>     5.5     4.0
>     1.0     5.0
>     5.0     2.5
>     2.0     2.0
>     4.0     2.0
>     1.0     1.5
```

Here is my program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[100];
FILE *fp;
int n=0;
int N;
double x[22];
double y[22];

int main(void) {
    printf("Input filename: ");
    fgets(filename, 100, stdin); //read filename
                                 //check if enter sign exist in filename

    N = (int)strlen(filename);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (filename[i] == '\n') {
            filename[i] = '\0';
        }
    }

    //printf("%s", filename);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); //open file
    if (fp == NULL) //check file
    {
        printf("\nCannot open input file %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);  //read Data
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fscanf(fp,"%f%f", &x[i], &y[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp); //close file
                //check data retrieved
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        printf("%f//%f//\n", x[i], y[i]);
    }
```

The result is 14 values of 0.0000 rather than values in the tab file.

Comment: try `fscanf(fp,"%lf%lf", &x[i], &y[i]);` since you have `double` data. And check return value of `fscanf`. Should be 2 for 2 values read.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Values are able to be stored now!

Comment: Please indent your code for the sanity of people in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I will indent my code next time.